# Live sorting of JTable

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, sorting, jtable

I've figured out how to get a `JTable` to be sorted properly, but I can't figure out how to get it to automatically update the sort order when a table cell is changed.  Right now, I have this (admittedly long) code, mostly based on that in the Java Tutorial's [How to Use Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). I've highlighted the changes I've made with `// ADDED`. In this case, newly-added values sort properly, but when I go in to edit a value, it doesn't seem to resort, even though I call `fireTableCellUpdated`?

In short, how can I get a table to re-sort when a data value changes in the model?

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995 - 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 * See the standard BSD license.
 */ 

package components;

/*
 * TableSortDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableSortDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableSortDemo() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(TableSortDemo.this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        final MyTableModel m = new MyTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(m);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);

        // ADDED: button to add a value
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add a new value");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m.addValue(
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                TableSortDemo.this, "Value?"));
            }
        });

        // ADDED button to change a value
        JButton setButton = new JButton("Change a value");
        setButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
             */
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m.setValueAt(
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                TableSortDemo.this, "Value?"),
                        Integer.parseInt(
                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                        TableSortDemo.this, "Which?")), 0);
            }
        });
        add(addButton);
        add(setButton);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7053335255134714625L;
        private String[] columnNames = {"Column"};
        // ADDED data as mutable ArrayList
        private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        public MyTableModel() {
            data.add("Anders");
            data.add("Lars");
            data.add("Betty");
            data.add("Anna");
            data.add("Jon");
            data.add("Zach");
        }

        // ADDED
        public void addValue(Object v) {
            data.add(v.toString());
            int row = data.size() - 1;
            fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data.get(row) + " " + row;
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class<String> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return String.class;
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data.set(row, value.toString());

            // ADDED: uncommented this line, despite warnings to the contrary
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableSortDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableSortDemo newContentPane = new TableSortDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This took a two-step solution:

First I had the TableSorter sort on data change, by using this rather than `autoCreateRowSorter`:

```
sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(m);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
```

Then, I had to change the update method to update the entire table.  The `fireTableCellUpdated` and the `fireTableRowsUpdated` would only redraw the specific rows that were updated, not the entire table (meaning you'd get a duplicate-appearing entry that changed as soon as it was redrawn later.  So, I changed

```
fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
```

to

```
fireTableRowsUpdated(0, data.size() - 1);
```

and now it sorts properly, even upon data changes, and selection is preserved.

Answer (score 4):

Its a [long-standing bug on JTable](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6539455), reported in 2007 (astonished that it isn't fixed, not even in jdk7)

Firing a update on all rows is a reasonable quick fix if it doesn't degrade performance too much (due to triggering frequent complete resorts). For the fearless, here's a partial fix on JTable - partial, because not yet all possible scenarios are captured. Which is the reason it never made it into JXTable (or maybe I had other priorities then :-)

```
public static class JTableRepaintOnUpdate extends JTable {

  private UpdateHandler beforeSort;
  
  @Override
  public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
      super.sorterChanged(e);
      maybeRepaintOnSorterChanged(e);
  } 

  private void beforeUpdate(TableModelEvent e) {
      if (!isSorted()) return;
      beforeSort = new UpdateHandler(e);
  }
  
  private void afterUpdate() {
      beforeSort = null;
  }
  
  private void maybeRepaintOnSorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
      if (beforeSort == null) return;
      if ((e == null) || (e.getType() != RowSorterEvent.Type.SORTED)) return;
      UpdateHandler afterSort = new UpdateHandler(beforeSort);
      if (afterSort.allHidden(beforeSort)) {
          return;
      } else if (afterSort.complex(beforeSort)) {
          repaint();
          return;
      }
      int firstRow = afterSort.getFirstCombined(beforeSort);
      int lastRow = afterSort.getLastCombined(beforeSort);
      Rectangle first = getCellRect(firstRow, 0, false);
      first.width = getWidth();
      Rectangle last = getCellRect(lastRow, 0, false);
      repaint(first.union(last));
  }
  
  private class UpdateHandler {
      private int firstModelRow;
      private int lastModelRow;
      private int viewRow;
      private boolean allHidden;
      
      public UpdateHandler(TableModelEvent e) {
          firstModelRow = e.getFirstRow();
          lastModelRow = e.getLastRow();
          convert();
      }
      
      public UpdateHandler(UpdateHandler e) {
          firstModelRow = e.firstModelRow;
          lastModelRow = e.lastModelRow;
          convert();
      }
      
      public boolean allHidden(UpdateHandler e) {
          return this.allHidden && e.allHidden;
      }
      
      public boolean complex(UpdateHandler e) {
          return (firstModelRow != lastModelRow);
      }
      
      public int getFirstCombined(UpdateHandler e) {
          if (allHidden) return e.viewRow;
          if (e.allHidden) return viewRow;
          return Math.min(viewRow, e.viewRow);
      }
      
      public int getLastCombined(UpdateHandler e) {
          if (allHidden || e.allHidden) return getRowCount() - 1;
          return Math.max(viewRow, e.viewRow);
          
      }

      private void convert() {
          // multiple updates
          if (firstModelRow != lastModelRow) {
              // don't bother too much - calculation not guaranteed to do anything good
              // just check if the all changed indices are hidden
              allHidden = true;
              for (int i = firstModelRow; i <= lastModelRow; i++) {
                  if (convertRowIndexToView(i) >= 0) {
                      allHidden = false;
                      break;
                  }
              }
              viewRow = -1;
              return;
          }
          // single update
          viewRow = convertRowIndexToView(firstModelRow);
          allHidden = viewRow < 0;
      }
      
  }

  private boolean isSorted() {
      // JW: not good enough - need a way to decide if there are any sortkeys which
      // constitute a sort or any effective filters  
      return getRowSorter() != null;
  }

  @Override
  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
      if (isUpdate(e)) {
          beforeUpdate(e);
      }
      try {
          super.tableChanged(e);
      } finally {
          afterUpdate();
      }
  }

  /**
   * Convenience method to detect dataChanged table event type.
   * 
   * @param e the event to examine. 
   * @return true if the event is of type dataChanged, false else.
   */
  protected boolean isDataChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
      if (e == null) return false;
      return e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE && 
          e.getFirstRow() == 0 &&
          e.getLastRow() == Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }
  
  /**
   * Convenience method to detect update table event type.
   * 
   * @param e the event to examine. 
   * @return true if the event is of type update and not dataChanged, false else.
   */
  protected boolean isUpdate(TableModelEvent e) {
      if (isStructureChanged(e)) return false;
      return e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE && 
          e.getLastRow() < Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }

  /**
   * Convenience method to detect a structureChanged table event type.
   * @param e the event to examine.
   * @return true if the event is of type structureChanged or null, false else.
   */
  protected boolean isStructureChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
      return e == null || e.getFirstRow() == TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW;
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow, great answer.  This was a years-ago co-op, and in my case, the hacky update-ALL-the-things! solution ended up working out just fine performance-wise.

Comment: Small update: The bug was closed in 2018 as "won't fix".

Answer (score 1):

probably the easiest way to get it sorted would be to call fireTableDataChanged() instead of fireTableCellUpdated().

Answer (score -1):

There are several things you have to do here.

1. Since the table model wraps your collection it has to be sortable. That means that your object (row) has to implement Comparable interface so collection can be properly sorted.
2. In your setValueAt method you have to to update appropriate attribute and resort the collection using Collections.sort. Then, obviously, you have to call fireTableDataChanged to let table know that it needs to redraw.
3. Same thing suppose to happen on adding data.
4. When data is removed you don't have to resort, but still have to fireTableDataChanged
5. If your collection is to big, you may think about adding data to appropriate place initially instead of resorting.

Hope this helps

Comment: Except in this case, I don't want the TableModel to be responsible for the sorting, I want that to be done by the Sorter in the view. As it stands, this method sorts the table properly, handles insertion properly, but does not handle changes properly.

Comment: Why don't you just expose the sort method on the model then?

Comment: IMO this will be proper MVC design. Table model represents data and should encapsulate related operations. This will let you fire proper events. By making it public you can call sorting from outside.

Comment: Sorting should be done in View layer. User can specific, "I want to sort by X. Opps, that's doesn't look nice. OK. Now, I want to view it by sort by Y."