# Does there exist a fix / best-practice approach for sorting JTables with dynamic model

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I found [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996948/live-sorting-of-jtable) regarding sorting a JTable whichs model is not "static" but elements may be added to it, automatically updating the sort order.
The accepted answer states:

> So, I changed
>
> *fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);*
>
> to
>
> *fireTableRowsUpdated(0, data.size() - 1);*
>
> and now it sorts properly, even upon data changes, and selection is preserved.

Since this question is now over 5 years old, with Java 8 and Co. happening, I wanted to ask if there is a new / better solution to achieve sorting.

In my model implementing `AbstractTableModel` I currently call

```
fireTableCellUpdated(newRowId, newColId);
```

when a new item is added.

The code in my UI looks the following:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setModel(myModel); // myModel is declared somewhere above
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
table.getRowSorter().setSortKeys(Arrays.asList(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING)));
```

Do I have to go with the solution proposed in the other question or is there some "better" / best-practice way to do this?

Comment: [`DefaultRowSorter#setSortsOnUpdates`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortsOnUpdates(boolean)). I would suggest that this has always been a better solution

Comment: Do you have a complete example on this? I've been on Google now for 30 minutes, but cannot really find a suitable example.

Comment: Do you have one that doesn't work?